# Unexpected token ')'

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script. I want to find files by series expression. I am using this line:

`find /etc \( \( -perm +222  -not -user root \) -or \( \(-perm -022 -or -perm -002 -or -perm -020 /) -user root /) /)  -ls`

I keep a error but the problem is that I get can't find is actually causing the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `/)`s should be `\)`. `\` escapes the next character.